# Does it matter which table has the foreign key in a one to one relationship?

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm designing my first relational database, and it's only a few tables, but I'm curious what the rules regarding foreign keys are.

In this specific case I have a have a table for a comment and a table for a reply to that comment. Should the foreign key be in the comment table,  pointing to the reply id, or should the foreign key be in the reply table, pointing to the comment id?

To me it seems like there's no real difference, but I was wondering if there's a convention that specifies how it should be done.

Comment: A comment could conceivably have more than one reply or none at all.  This is not a 1-1 relationship.

Comment: So you can never have more than 1 reply to a comment?  Ever?

Comment: I learned about 1-1 relationships in computer school, but I have never seen an actual situation where it was appropriate.

Comment: In fact you could possibly have reply on replies (multiple levels).  So maybe you only want a single table where the foreign key is pointing to another record in the same table that contains both comments and replies. (The top comment record would have a null foreign key)

Comment: @Dan: I've actually seen such cases, though not too many of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easy answer is the answer to the question "what depends on what"?  In your case, does there need to be a comment before there is a reply?  Is there functional dependency?  If yes, then the "parent" is the comment table, and the "child" is the reply table.  So then you'd want to put a FK on the reply table pointing to the comment table.

So you are enforcing that there is a comment that always exists that the reply points to.  If that lines up with the reality of the system, then the FK makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question

Comment: Not a problem.  I don't presume to know your business reqs, so the cardinality of the relationship wasn't as important.